# installation error on parrot os for program "beEF"

Tags: parrot-os

i have just got parrot os and would like to download and run beEF, i can download the folder, but when i try to run the install command i get the following message:

> E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 4982 (apt)
> N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
> E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another >process using it?

Im new to all this, i have switched the computer on and off to make sure there is no other process using it.

Does anyone know what i need to do?

Kind regards

Answer (score -1):

It happens because u run command to install/update/upgrade on another terminal. Kill the session and try again

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).